# Why does cabal download and compile from source?

Tags: haskell, cabal, dynamic-linking

When I make a new project. Say, a web app using Snap. 
I generate the skeleton using `snap init barebones`, make a new sandbox and then install the dependencies.

This takes forever. Seriously. If you have ever worked with pretty much any other web framework (node.js with express, for example), the process is nearly identical but takes a fraction of the time. I'm aware that most node dependencies do not require any compilation but I find it really strange that this isn't considered a bigger problem. For example, I will never be able to run a Yesod app on my cheap VPS because the VPS isn't powerful enough to compile it and I can't really upload 500mb of precompiled libraries.

The question is, why doesn't the repository host binaries instead of just code?
.NET is also compiled (to bytecode) but I can use it's DLLs without any need for recompilation.

There are of course drawbacks of hosting binaries like more storage space needed, multiple binaries per library for multiple OSs... But all the problems seems insignificant to the huge benefits that you get such as

- No more compile errors
- Much faster setup for new projects
- Significantly less memory needed
- Knowing that a library doesn't support your OS BEFORE you find out for yourself

I have trouble seeing why cabal hell exists in the first place. If all the libraries were available for dynamic linking, wouldn't the need for recompiling simply not exist at all?

Currently, one has to try really hard to stick with Haskell in these regards. It seems like the system punishes me for trying out things. If I want to add a new library to my project I have to be sure I'm willing to wait for 15-45(!!!) minutes for it to compile. Not to mention that a library fails to compile way more often than I'm comfortable with. After surviving the process, only then can I actually figure out if that library is what I want to use, or if it's even compatible with the rest of my project.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Hey. My question was nothing but civil and every part of it, while admittedly anecdotal, is true. If you have trouble keeping your temperament down, don't answer, but there's no reason to downvote or call me uneducated. Feel free to educate me or let someone else do it.

Comment: I think this question is simply bad, and hence my downvote. That's the reason enough, per the site rules.

Comment: .NET is not usually compiled to bytecode, it's is compiled to CIL, which is a "cross platform" assembly-like language, sort of like LLVM.  You can download libraries from NuGet relatively quickly because it can grab something that .NET in particular can understand.  Try doing that with C, you'll have a hard time.  Even with DLLs, you have to have different binaries depending on 32 bit, 64 bit, sometimes architecture, and if you want good optimizations you have to compile from source.  Haskell has chosen the route of performance, and the support of multiple OSes, unlike .NET.

Comment: @bheklilr Do you have any statistical data on the performance gains?

Comment: "multiple binaries per library for multiple OSs ... Knowing that a library doesn't support your OS BEFORE you find out for yourself" - except the part where either the library maintainers or Hackage has to be able to build for every single platform, OS, architecture, and all the combinations of those.  This means multiple versions of Windows, Ubuntu, OSX, Arch Linux, CentOS, RedHat, the list goes on.  This is far too complicated a task to ask of a single service, when you have the capability of building it yourself.

Comment: @LukaHorvat Comparing performance of languages and libraries is hard (TLDR measuring one use case gives you data about that one use case and little to nothing else). What's well known is that [Haskell *is* fast](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=ghc&lang2=csharp&data=u64q), if you need it, for such a high level language. Even then though, performance (or rather, *possibility of optimizations*) is just one of the concerns.

Comment: @LukaHorvat .NET CIL is actually JIT compiled, so it can end up being pretty speedy, but whenever you're talking about performance there are certain tasks that almost any language will beat others at.  [That](http://www.slideshare.net/pt114/haskell-vs-f-vs-scala) being [said](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/ndp/haskell-beats-C.pdf), there are cases that Haskell can even beat C on numeric computations.

Comment: @bheklilr Is it that big of a task for hackage to compile the libraries? I mean, if you're making a library that you want others to use, you're going to have to make sure it works everywhere anyways. I'd say it's much more reasonable to expect that a centralized system is responsible for cross-compilation. This is of course nothing but a feeling so I'm aware I might be completely wrong.

Comment: @LukaHorvat Yes, it's very hard.  The Hackage server is hosted on a particular OS.  For every project hosted no matter how many downloads it has, you'd have to be able to cross-compile for every other platform, OS, bit-count, and specific hardware in some cases.  You could build more generic ones for linux, windows, and osx in 32 and 64 bit, but that doesn't give the programmer much control over profiling, debugging, and optimizations.  It's much harder to do these things on an already compiled binary.

Comment: Remember that Haskell is not Microsoft or Oracle, they don't have lots of money to throw at problems like this, it's mostly run by volunteers and members of the community.  Resources are a huge issue, and while the community is full of very talented people, the community is still very small.  Just ask yourself how many use Java, JS, C#, or Python, and compare that to the number of people using Haskell.  If you think Hackage could be improved, the best route would be for you to become a contributor, go fix some bugs or implement a new feature.

Comment: @bheklilr I seems like the best contribution would be to become rich and throw money at Haskell :D

Comment: @LukaHorvat Then Godspeed, and let me know how you became rich so I can too.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell: because native code is hard.

If you want to host binaries for arbitrary systems, you have to match the binaries to each system you want to run on.  That may mean compiling dozens of sets of binaries to support all of the systems the code will compile on.

On the other hand, you may well find that someone *has* compiled the code you need: your distribution provider may well provide packages for the Haskell libraries you need.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's the easiest way to distribute everything while keeping it up to date. By offloading build costs to the users, library authors only need to provide source code.

This can be mitigated in various ways. For example, [my CI setup](https://github.com/bananu7/potato-empires) uses CircleCI and Heroku. Nodes on both hold precached cabal sandboxes (it's actually very easy to set up). I build my project on Heroku, but there's no reason why you couldn't take prebuilt artifacts from your CI and deploy them directly.

As for dynamic linking, there's a possibility to link Haskell modules dynamically, but shared libraries more often than not are a source of problems. One look at Windows DLL hell should be enough to see this, and most commercial applications simply ship DLLs they use anyway. If a library changes, the DLLs have to be replaced anyway, and the way Cabal does it makes it simplest to have latest and greatest versions of everything.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that on *some* platforms, you *can* in fact install binary libraries. For example, on my OpenSUSE Linux system, YaST will quite happily download and install certain Haskell libraries, without having to build anything from source.

Of course, this only covers a fairly small set of libraries, and all the RPMs will be many months out of date. (Not a big deal for X11, kind of a deal-breaker for something like Yesod that's under heavy development...)

I think another big part of the problem is that if you compile a Haskell library with GHC 7.6.4, then you *cannot* use that binary compiled library with GHC 7.8.3. So we're not just talking about one compiled binary for each OS; we're talking about one compiled binary for every OS + GHC minor point-release combination.

Oh, and did I mention? If you compile Yesod 1.4.0 against ByteString 0.9.2.0, then that compiled binary is *useless* if your system has ByteString 0.9.2.1 installed. So you potentially need one compiled binary for every OS, every GHC release, and every release of every library that it transitively depends on.

...This is partly why the Haskell Platform was invented. It's a single binary download that gives you a big heap of code that you don't need to compile from source, and where all the versions of the libraries in it are mutually compatible. (No dependency hell - the Haskell Platform maintainers sort that out for you!)

I do agree that binary packages would be extremely nice to have. But the above problems make it unlikely, IMHO.

Comment: Wouldn't dynamic linking solve a lot of these? A library ships it's dependencies with itself. If two libraries in the dependency tree use the same version of the same library, the package manager makes sure they use the same file to avoid duplication.

Comment: We I say, it requires somebody to sit down and work out what versions of everything to use, so it all works together. Rather like what the maintainers of the Linux distro have to do. I don't know if anybody has the time and energy to do that. Whereas, making all the source available lets people solve the problem themselves. (Slowly.)